# Open Twitter application user profile from Android application

Tags: android, twitter

I'm able to start Twitter application (if it exists on the phone), yet I can't find how to automatically display a specific user profile.

Something like this works for Google+:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus", "com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity");
intent.putExtra("customAppUri", "USER_ID");
```

Here is the Facebook way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/USER_ID"));
startActivity(intent);
```

There should be the same kind of solution when I start Twitter app ?

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.twitter.android");
intent.putExtra("WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?", "USER_ID");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
try {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=" + twitter_user_name)));
}catch (Exception e) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/" + twitter_user_name)));
}
```

This is working fine with the new Twitter app. Solution provided by @Baptiste Costa didn't work for me.

Comment: confirmed;
but : getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0); + try/catch on NameNotFoundException is still useful to fallback on webapp ( my use case is passing the intent to a notification, so I need to know in advance what will work - that's the most straightforward option ).

Comment: Is this supposed to be with our without `@` ?

Comment: @JonasB it's without '@' sign

Answer (score 17):

```
try
{
    // Check if the Twitter app is installed on the phone.
    getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.ProfileActivity");
    // Don't forget to put the "L" at the end of the id.
    intent.putExtra("user_id", 01234567L);
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e)
{
    // If Twitter app is not installed, start browser.
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/AndroTesteur")));
}
```

Comment: this's worked on emulator which run into catch. And also worked well on my device which installed twitter app after I change user_id to screen_name, intentTW.putExtra("screen_name", twitterProfile);

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, I would like to shed some light into it. I have done it using either the user id or the username if that fails.

```
Intent intent;
try {
    // Check if the Twitter app is installed on the phone.
    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);

    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=813679215195410432"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/LynxMods"));
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```